# css content: not displaying in firefox

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to css a site that has woocommerce running and I want to use an image to replace the on sale badge. My current css

```
.product .onsale {
content: url(https://..../uploads/2017/01/badge-cookie-month.gif) !important;
margin-right: 0;
border-radius:0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding:0;
max-width:30%;
}
```

Works in everything but Firefox. Any way of making this work

Comment: You should post the existing CSS and relevant HTML too, or better yet, make a JS Fiddle with the example demonstrating all the pieces.

Comment: @MichaelEdelstone it's advised to include all relevant code in the SO post - not linking to 3rd parties like codepen/jsfiddle unless absolutely necessary. If something happens to the 3rd party site or their URLs change or whatever, references to them won't work in SO posts. It's covered here. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can't use `content` like that. The URL is also invalid (unless you have deleted the domain part deliberately).

Comment: the domain part was removed. last time i posted someone said to remove it.